# Rails/ActiveAdmin form: how to disable an input field based on the value of another (boolean) input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model that has a boolean field and an array field that gets the values populated from another model (foreign key, not really relevant to my question).

In ActiveAdmin, I have a form like such:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs do
    f.input :boolean_field_name
    f.input :array_field_name,
            as: :searchable_select,
            ajax: true,
            input_html: { disabled: true }
  end
  f.actions
end
```

The `disabled: true` works, but I would like to replace the `true` with something that evaluates whether or not the input checkbox for `boolean_field_name` has been checked on the form (which by default it isn't).

I've tried `params[:boolean_field_name]`, `params.key?[:boolean_field_name]`, `f.object.boolean_field_name`, `f.object[:boolean_field_name]`, `resource[:boolean_field_name]` and `resource.boolean_field_name`, but they all do nothing and evaluate to nil as far as I can tell.

I've even tried `ModelName.find(params[:id]).boolean_field_name` but of course since `params[:id]` is nil that doesn't work, and it wouldn't find a record with that id anyway because the record hasn't been created yet.

I've tried looking through the ActiveAdmin repository but I can't find the information I'm looking for in the source code either.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like this?

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs do
    f.input :boolean_field_name
    f.input :array_field_name,
            as: :searchable_select,
            ajax: true,
            input_html: { disabled: f.object.boolean_field_name # <= does not work }
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Since the information is a bit ambiguous to me, I would firstly like to know:

- From the description:

> The disabled: true works, but I would like to replace the true with
> something that evaluates whether or not the input checkbox for
> boolean_field_name has been checked on the form (which by default it
> isn't).

Did you mean that you wanna change the `disabled` attribute depending on the other form field ***after the page loads***? If that's true, then you have to do it with javascript as something like this:

```
let booleanField = document.querySelector('booleanField'),
    arrayField = document.querySelector('arrayField');

booleanField.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  arrayField.setAttribute('disabled', booleanField.value);
})
```

Or if you mean you just wanna set the value of the `disabled` attribute to what `boolean_field` initially is on page loads, it will bring us more information if you can debug with the tools like `debug`, `debugger` or `binding.pry`. It will be helpful to checkout what `f.object.boolean_field_name` returns. According to the information you provides, I guess it could really be `nil`.

Comment: You understood me correctly, and yes I do want the array field's input to be disabled reactively based on whether or not the boolean field's input is checked on the form. Unfortunately I cannot use JS for this because the Rails ActiveAdmin resource is on a separate repository (and also hosted separately) to the UI.

Comment: You can simply embed a javascript into the html template(wether `erb` or `haml`) by inserting `<script>`. Or just create a js file and included in the asset pipeline. You don't have to do it in the repository of `ActiveAdmin`.

Comment: There are no templates either. The UI renders ActiveAdmin via API only. Please believe me, I know it's a weird setup, but I cannot use JS to solve this problem. Which is why I'm not even sure it's possible.